# How to solve ORA-01006 in procedure?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I need to have a procedure to calculate count of something and insert it into another table but get error

> ORA-01006:bind variable does not exist.

Here is my code:

[image]

Insert part is not be executed and jumps to exception instead.

Comment: For future reference please do not post your code as an image. Many people are unable to view images in dump sites, and the code is pretty unreadable anyway. So you are just reducing the pool of people who might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your dynamic SQL call is

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING v_result;
```

This is the syntax for passing a parameter into the dynamic statement. But your code **doesn't take any parameters**, because you have concatenated them in the string. Therefore, the code hurls ORA-01006.

What you need to do instead is provide a variable for the result set to be return into. So the call should be

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO v_result;
```

The syntax for EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is comprehensively covered in [the PL/SQL guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#GUID-30ADFC05-8DFB-4C8A-831D-426C2E97F217). You should bookmark the Oracle documentation for future reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot working, also I change v_sql content to be 'select sum(P2P) as Su'